# In what order does Python execute code & assign values to variables within nested functions?

Tags: python

Similar questions have been asked to this about local variable assignments, but this question has to do with the order in which Python executes code.

Please Refer to the following code:

```
def b1():
    x = 1

    def b2():
        print(x)
        x = 2
    b2()


b1()
```

I would expect the result to be:

```
1
2
```

Instead, it kicks out an error:

`UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment`

I would expect print to succeed, because it does succeed if you remove `x = 2` from the code. With it still present, x has been declared in b1(), so it should be available for b2() - so, it would seem the only way Python knows that x is a local variable when it hits the print(x) statement is if it *looked ahead* to see the local variable declared!

Am I missing something? When viewing the `locals()` object before print is called, the table is empty. So how would python know there is a local variable x later on in b2()?

Comment: Try `global x`.

Comment: To clarify, I am used to having to debug by looking at preceding code, not code which follows. But, to remove this error, which occurs at print(x), one can remove x=2 which is code *after* the print statement. I know I can use global and / or nonlocal statements to get things to work as I want. But, that is not my concern. I am really just trying to understand why the code as it is above is behaving the way it is.

Comment: Well, the `x` from `x = 1` belongs to a different scope and is therefore not present in the scope of  `b2`

Comment: @inspectorG4dget This question is "Explain to me the concept involved", not "How do I get this code to do something different?"

Comment: @inspectorG4dget In this case, `nonlocal x` would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scope of the name `x` in `b2` is determined at compile time; the fact that you assign to `x` makes it a local variable *throughout* the function. The fact that `print(x)` comes before `x = 2` doesn't matter; you are trying to print a *local* variable that hasn't yet been assigned to.

Since the intent is for `b2` to act on the `x` defined in `b1`, it needs to be declared as `nonlocal`:

```
def b1():
    x = 1

    def b2():
        nonlocal x
        print(x)
        x = 2
    b2()


b1()
```

Now, the `nonlocal` statement will prevent the assignment from making it a local variable. `print(x)` will print the current value of `x` as determined by the lexical scope (here, the `x` defined in `b1)`, and `x = 2` will likewise change the
value of `b1`'s `x`.

Comment: nice explanation. If I wanted to look deeper into this, I suppose I would look into the symtable module.